# Apply 2 background images to one HTML element from different CSS classes

Tags: html, css, less

I applied 2 CSS classes to a `div` [Online Example](https://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/JjJwQBV):

```
<div class="img1 img2">
</div>
```

Using LESS I tried to apply 2 background images to the `div`, one from each class:

```
div {
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  
  &.img1 {
    background+: url('https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f/fff') no-repeat left top;
  } // img1
  
  &.img2 {
    background+: url('https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f/fff') no-repeat right bottom;
  } // img2
  
}
```

But only the second background is applied.

Isn't Less's [merge](https://lesscss.org/features/#merge-feature) feature for this?

Comment: A single DOM element can only have one background image.  `merge` lets you combine multiple declarations into one, but not of the exact same rule

Comment: It's not a less thing, you can't specify multiple background images across multiple rules

Comment: Is there a reason for not having a .img1.img2 setting with both images in the background property value?

Comment: @AHaworth I will have 20 images and I will have 2 of them. It changes from page to page. So I would have a lot of combinations ...

Comment: How about putting img2 on a pseudo element then you don't have to combine them in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to include multiple backgrounds into a single element:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds

```css
.multi-bg-example {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f/fff'),
          url('https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f/fff');
  background-repeat: no-repeat,
          no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom left,
          top right;
 }
```

```html
<div class="multi-bg-example" />
```

so you set props one by one and they applie to the corresponding backgrounds.